# JQuery fadeIn issue

Tags: jquery, fadein

I have been given the task of converting a Flash animation to JQuery. This is what I am trying to get my Jquery code to do, here is the flash animation: http://www.thedesigncommonwealth.com/durangoSlideshow.html.

This is my Jquery looks like so far: http://www.lisa.netii.net/test-for-durango.html

I'm working on the left side first, just trying to get this to work properly before moving on the the other side, the timing is very important between the two sides and I think my code so far may be able to handle that. There are a couple of obvious problems when viewing the Jquery version. To start with, I'm having trouble with the fadeIn effect. All the images except for the first one pop unto the screen, even when I use the .hide effect. I have tried using the .hide in each of the Jquery function lines for each div and it only seems to work for the first image, all the other images still just pop onto the screen.

There's also a problem with the first slide. What's currently #slide2 in the html is supposed to be slide1, but for some reason the animation starts running on slide2 while nothing happens on #slide1, so I changed #slide1 to #slide2, but that is obviously not a good fix. I can take this a step at a time...

Can anyone tell me what I can do to fix the fadeIn issue?
Here is my Jquery code:

```
$("#slide1").hide().fadeIn(200).delay(3000).fadeOut(4000);
var t2 = setTimeout(function(){
    $("#slide2").hide().fadeIn(4000).delay(5000).fadeOut(4000);
    var t3 = setTimeout(function(){
        $("#slide3").hide().fadeIn(4000).delay(10000).fadeOut(4000);
        var t4 = setTimeout(function(){
            $("#slide4").hide().fadeIn(4000).delay(5000).fadeOut(4000);
            var t5 = setTimeout(function(){        
                $("#slide5").hide().fadeIn(4000);
            }, 6500);
        }, 11500);
    }, 6500);
}, 6500);
```

To view the css and html see the jquery website link.

Thank you so much for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var numberOfImages = 5;
var fadeInSpeed = 200;
var fadeOutSpeed = 200;
var pause = 6500;

function startSlideImage(index) {
   jQuery('#slide'+index).hide().fadeIn(200, function(){
      jQuery(this).delay(3000).fadeOut(fadeOutSpeed, function(){
         setTimeout(function(){
            startSlideImage(index+1);
         }, pause);
      });
   });
}

startSlideImage(1);
```

To add different Delay-Times, you can write this data into a class-attribute like:

```
<div id="slide1" class="delay-3000">...</div>
```

or any other Attribute that is not used and w3c-konform. But class-Attribute is the best in my opinion. If class-Attribute has other values, you can split it by space .split(' ') and catch the index.

After that you can read out the Delay with:

```
var delay = parseInt(jQuery('#slide1').attr('class').replace('delay-',''), 10);
```

So your Function should be look like this:

```
function startSlideImage(index) {
   jQuery('#slide'+index).hide().fadeIn(200, function(){
      var delay = parseInt(jQuery('#slide1').attr('class').replace('delay-',''), 10);
      jQuery(this).delay(delay).fadeOut(fadeOutSpeed, function(){
         setTimeout(function(){
            startSlideImage(index+1);
         }, pause);
      });
   });
}
```

Comment: I need to be able to add a different delay value on each div/slide. I'm not sure how I can do that in this example. Maybe if there was an explanation of the code above...? Thank you Richarz.